¿En qué idioma está y cuál es la traducción de "Mallorca no es ven"?

Creo que puedo adivinar lo que dice este  letrero, pero ¿qué idioma es y qué parte de la oración es "ven"?.

El idioma es catalán (o mallorquín que es la variedad local de catalán para los que se ofenden si alguien dice que en las Baleares se habla algo más que castellano e inglés, como si eso fuese a fortalecer al independentismo catalán). Y lo que seguramente adivinaste es que el letrero dice: Mallorca no se vende, por lo tanto el verbo es ven (la forma catal... mallorquina que diga, de decir vende).

Es Catalán:

Mallorca no se vende

Mallorca forma parte de las Islas Baleares donde se habla el Catalán además del Castellano.

Las Islas Baleares no pertenecen a la comunidad autónoma de Cataluña. Son una comunidad autónoma ellas mismas https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islas_Baleares.

Ah, ok, las tenía asociadas por ser territorio catalán, lo cambio

@wimi pero en las Baleares se habla también catalán, que no es idéntico al catalán central de Barcelona, pero también se habla y para muestra la pancarta de la foto.
